# openpyxl save function is destructively altering the workbook, preventing subsequent reads from working correctly

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I'm currently running into an issue with the openpyxl library for Python 2.7.  The version is 2.6.4 (i.e., the latest release for Python 2.7)

The issue I'm having is as follows:

I have an excel workbook with several sheets in it.  One of these sheets `MySheet` has some cells that contain formulas.  For example, cell `B2` has the formula `=Start!$Z1` (which references cell `Z1` in a different sheet named `Start`).  Now obviously, when viewing this file in excel, the formula works as expected and cell `B1` shows the same value contained in `Z1` in the `Start` sheet.

So far so good.

Next, I load this workbook in python, read `B1` to ensure that it has the correct value, and then save it as follows:

```
f = "C:/my_workbook.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=f, data_only=True)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("MySheet")

# The following line returns the expected value output from the formula, because I set data_only=True above
# If I had instead set data_only=False above, then this would have spit out "=Start!$Z1" (as expected)
value = sheet["B1"].value

wb.save(filename="output.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

This `output.xlsx` file looks the same as the original `my_workbook.xlsx` file that I loaded, and everything displays correctly in Excel, however its file size is slightly larger.

Now, when I attempt to run the exact same code as above, except using `f = "C:/output.xlsx`, the value returned by reading `sheet[B1].value` is now `None`.

It's as if saving the original `my_workbook.xlsx` somehow corrupted the file, preventing openpyxl from being able to retrieve the value from cells containing formulas.  For what it's worth, I can still read non-formula cells just fine, and they return the correct values.  For whatever reason though, any cell that contains a formula simply returns `None` after the original save operation.

Has anyone observed this behaviour before?  Am I missing something here?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Exactly how are you reading the file back again? What if you saved it as a csv?

Comment: Could you share an example workbook? See: [mcve].

Comment: @MattCremeens It's being read back exactly as I have in the example above - the same way it was originally read-in.  It is being saved out as an XLSX file.

Comment: Don't use `wb.save(...` if you do `.load_workbook(..., data_only=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post a follow up to this problem.  I wasn't able to solve the initial problem with openpyxl, but I instead switched to xlwings and no longer experienced this problem.

My understanding is that xlwings actually establishes a connection to Excel via win32 (or equivalent on MacOS) whereas openpyxl deals with the raw data format (OOXML).

So, for anyone who may be reading this in the future and happens to be experiencing the same (or similar) issue - I'm sorry I don't have better advice to solve the problem directly, but I'd happily recommend xlwings as my experience has been pretty good using it thus far.